# How to take argv starting at specific index

Tags: c

I want to pass argv to execvp but starting at a certain index i other than 0. How do I do that? I thought of copying the arguments starting at i into another array and use that array but the number of arguments is not fixed and doesn't look like that's possible without dynamic allocation which I'm new to. I think there is a simpler way to just have argv point to i but I can't figure it out.

```
execvp(command, argv); //need argv to start at index 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since argv is an array, you can simply write `&argv[1]` for example to pass the second argument and forth.

So for your case: `execvp(command, &argv[3]);`, just make sure argc is larger than 3.

Comment: I think this approach could be a little fragile. The reason is that `execvp()` will expect to receive an `argv` array for which `argv[0]` is the program name. That _might_ be the case in your example, but I'm not sure it can be guaranteed. Allocating a new `argv` dynamically is not difficult, and uses techniques that it's hard to master C without knowing.